# calculadora de windows en c# que permita ingreso por teclado

Tags: c#

Bien chicos, soy estudiante de último año de bachillerato, y tal y como dice en el titulo necesito que me ayuden en la realización de la calculadora básica(cosa que ya la tengo funcional con el mouse), pero ahora necesito adaptarla para que me acepte valores por teclado(ya saben, números, las operaciones y el botón de borrar, y que cuando le dé a enter, me dé el resultado) cosa con lo que he tenido muchos problemas.

Los números ya me los ingresa, pero no lo demás mencionado, espero que me ayuden es urgente, soy novato y es la primera vez que hago algo así.

Aquí les dejo el código para que puedan chequearlo, está todo comentado, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool detectaopreacion = true;
        string operacion;
        double result;
        double numero1;
        double numero2;
        bool punto = true;
        string borrado, point;
        double Signos;
        double memoria;
        bool labelmemory = false

        //Instrucciones para botones numericos
        private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtrespuesta.Text == "0")
            {
                return;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "0";
            }
        }
        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "1";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "1";
            }

        }
        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "2";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "2";
            }
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "3";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "3";
            }
        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "4";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "4";
            }
        }

        private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "5";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "5";
            }
        }

        private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "6";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "6";
            }
        }

        private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "7";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "7";
            }
        }

        private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "8";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "8";
            }
        }

        private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (detectaopreacion)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                txtrespuesta.Text = "9";
                detectaopreacion = false;

            }
            else
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + "9";
            }
        }

        //Fin de asignación númerica

            //Botones de operaciones, asignación
            //suma
        private void btnmas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operacion = "+";
            detectaopreacion = true;
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
        }

        //resta
        private void btnmenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operacion = "-";
            detectaopreacion = true;
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
        }
        //Multiplicación
        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operacion = "*";
            detectaopreacion = true;
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
        }
        //División
        private void btndividir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operacion = "/";
            detectaopreacion = true;
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
        }
        //Raiz Cuadrada
        private void btnraiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            result = Math.Sqrt(numero1);
            txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
            detectaopreacion = true;
        }
        //Potencia
        private void cuadrado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            result = numero1 * numero1;
            txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
        }
        //Porcentaje
        private void btnporcentaje_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numero1 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            result = ((numero1 * numero2) / 100);
            txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
            detectaopreacion = true;
        }
        //Fin de operaciones

            //Botón de igualdad, y llamado de operaciones
        private void btnigual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numero2 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            detectaopreacion = true;
            switch (operacion)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = numero1 + numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = numero1 - numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = numero1 * numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = numero1 / numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;

            }
        }
        //Boton Igual
        private void btnpunto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (punto == true)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + ".";
                punto = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            detectaopreacion = false;
        }

        //Botón limpiar todo
        private void btnce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
            numero1 = 0;
            numero2 = 0;
            detectaopreacion = true;
            punto = true;
        }
        //Botón limpiar 
        private void btnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
            detectaopreacion = true;
            numero1 = 0;
            numero2 = 0;
            result = 0;
        }

        //Boton retroceso/eliminado unitario
        private void btnretroceso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            borrado = txtrespuesta.Text;
            point = txtrespuesta.Text;
            x = borrado.Length - 1;
            y = point.Length - 1;
            point = point.Substring(y, 1);
            borrado = borrado.Substring(0, x);
            txtrespuesta.Text = borrado;
            if (txtrespuesta.Text == "")
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
                detectaopreacion = true;
            }
            if (txtrespuesta.Text == "-")
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
                detectaopreacion = true;
            }
            if (point == ".")
            {
                punto = true;
            }
        }

        //Boton memory clear(borrar memoria)
        private void btnmc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = 0;
            labelmemory = false;
        }
        //Boton more memory (Más memoria)
        private void btnmr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = memoria.ToString();
        }
        //Boton MS(no me acuerdo de las siglas, zorry :p)
        private void btnms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            labelmemory = true;
        }
        //Boton memoria +
        private void btnmmas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = memoria + Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            labelmemory = true;
        }
        //Boton memoria -
        private void btnmmenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = memoria - Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            labelmemory = true;
        }
        //Boton +-
        private void btnmasmenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Signos = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            Signos = Signos - (Signos * 2);
            txtrespuesta.Text = Signos.ToString();
        }

        //evento de validacion para admitir numeros por teclado
        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            switch(e.KeyChar.ToString())
            {
                case "0":
                    btn0.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    btn1.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    btn2.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    btn3.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    btn4.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    btn5.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    btn6.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "7":
                    btn7.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "8":
                    btn8.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "9":
                    btn9.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "+":
                    btnmas_Click();

                    break;
                case "-":
                    btnmenos.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    btnmul.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    btndividir.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "s":
                    cuadrado.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "Enter":
                    btnigual_Click();
                    break;



            }

        }
        private void btnigual_Click()
        {
            btnigual.PerformClick();
            numero2 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            detectaopreacion = true;
            switch (operacion)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = numero1 + numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = numero1 - numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = numero1 * numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = numero1 / numero2;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = result.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void fuelEconomiToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void editarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cientificaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form Form2 = new Form2();
            Form2.Show();
        }

        private void btnmas_Click()
        {
            detectaopreacion = true;
            numero2 = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ppuedes usar el keypress del form y darle un switch para cada caso de los numeros y ya las operaciones no entendi si tambien con teclado pero tambien se puede

Comment: Tu código parece correcto. Asegurate de que tu formulario tenga la propiedad `KeyPreview` a `true`, por si fuera posible que algun otro control se estuviera "tragando" el evento de pulsación de teclado.

Comment: No queda claro cual es el problema. Primero dices que tienes problemas para introducir valores por teclado ("números, operaciones,...") y luego comentas que los números ya te los ingresa. ¿Te reconoce unas teclas sí y otras no? ¿No te reconoce ninguna por teclado?

Comment: Si entiendo bien, lo que quieres es que en lugar de dar clic al boton + en tu pantalla, lo hagas en tu teclado correcto? Si es así, busca el evento key press en tu textbox o formulario y puedes utilizar las propiedades que visual te ofrece para capturar las teclas que presionas, por ejemplo:

    case Keys.Down:
    Console.WriteLine("Se tocó la flecha para abajo!!!!");
    break;

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Exacto, ya logre que me deje ingresar los numeros por teclado, y tambien los botones de operación, pero luego presiono enter y no pasa nada, igualmente con con el boton de borrar

Comment: No se como hacer para que presionando el punto, me lo escriba en la calculadora

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar la pulsación del punto no tienes más que añadir a la instrucción `switch` un `case` con la cadena `"."`.

El caso de la tecla suprimir es más complicado ya que no genera el evento `KeyPress`, para detectarlo deberías capturar el evento `KeyDown`.

En cualquier caso hay varias cosas mejorables en tu código.

Ya que el mismo código puede lanzarse desde diferentes eventos (clicks de botones, pulsaciones de teclado, ...) lo mejor sería que iel datmplementaras la funcionalidad en métodos separados y que llamaras a estos métodos desde los diferentes eventos. Es decir puedes crear un método que implemente la funcionalidad de suma y llamar a este método desde el evento `Click` del botón de suma y desde el evento `KeyPress` en caso de que la tecla pulsada sea un `+`.

Por otro lado, ya que el dato que se muestra en el `TextBox` no siempre es el mismo (unas veces es el primer número, otras el segundo, otras el resultado) deberías independizar la lógica de cálculo de lo que se esté mostrando en el `TextBox` llevando esos valores en variables independientes y mostrando en cada momento el valor que desees en el control.

Además hay mucho código repetido que podrías ahorrarte. Por ejemplo, en el caso de los botones de números, si estableces el carácter asociado al botón en la propiedad `Tag` de éste  o lo tomas del texto del botón, podrías utilizar un único controlador para el evento `Click` de todos los botones.

Me he venido arriba y he hecho un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar el código de una calculadora tal y como la planteas.

Aquí tienes el código. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string _valorActual = "";
    private double _resultado;
    private char _operacionPendiente;
    private readonly TextBox _display;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _display = new TextBox { Left = 10, Top = 10, Width = 240, ReadOnly = true, TabStop = false };
        Controls.Add(_display);

        EventHandler btnClick = (sender, args) => { TeclaPulsada((char)((Button)sender).Tag); };

        for (int i = 1, btnLeft = 10, btnTop = 190;
            i < 10;
            i++, btnLeft += btnLeft == 110 ? -100 : 50, btnTop -= btnLeft == 10 ? 50 : 0)
        {
            var btn = new Button { Left = btnLeft, Top = btnTop, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = i.ToString(), Tag = char.Parse(i.ToString()), TabStop = false };
            btn.Click += btnClick;
            Controls.Add(btn);
        }
        var btn0 = new Button { Left = 10, Top = 240, Width = 90, Height = 40, Text = @"0", Tag = '0', TabStop = false };
        btn0.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btn0);
        var btnDot = new Button { Left = 110, Top = 240, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @".", Tag = '.', TabStop = false };
        btnDot.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnDot);
        char[] operaciones = { '±', '/', '*', '-', '+' };
        for (var i = 0; i < operaciones.Length; i++)
        {
            var btnOperation = new Button { Left = 160, Top = 40 + 50 * i, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = operaciones[i].ToString(), Tag = operaciones[i], TabStop = false };
            btnOperation.Click += btnClick;
            Controls.Add(btnOperation);
        }
        var btnRaiz = new Button { Left = 210, Top = 40, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @"raíz", Tag = 'r', TabStop = false };
        btnRaiz.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnRaiz);
        var btnPorcentaje = new Button { Left = 210, Top = 90, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @"%", Tag = '%', TabStop = false };
        btnPorcentaje.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnPorcentaje);
        var btnInverso = new Button { Left = 210, Top = 140, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @"1/x", Tag = 'i', TabStop = false };
        btnInverso.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnInverso);

        var btnEnter = new Button { Left = 210, Top = 190, Width = 40, Height = 90, Text = @"=", Tag = '=', TabStop = false };
        btnEnter.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnEnter);
        var btnBack = new Button { Left = 10, Top = 40, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @"<--", Tag = '\b', TabStop = false };
        btnBack.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnBack);
        var btnCe = new Button { Left = 60, Top = 40, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @"CE", Tag = 'e', TabStop = false };
        btnCe.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnCe);
        var btnC = new Button { Left = 110, Top = 40, Width = 40, Height = 40, Text = @"C", Tag = 'c', TabStop = false };
        btnC.Click += btnClick;
        Controls.Add(btnC);

        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyPress += (sender, args) => { TeclaPulsada(args.KeyChar); };
        KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
        {
            switch (args.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Delete:
                    TeclaPulsada('e');
                    break;
                case Keys.Escape:
                    TeclaPulsada('c');
                    break;
            }
        };
        Width = 280;
        Height = 350;
    }

    private void TeclaPulsada(char key)
    {
        // Es un número
        if (char.IsDigit(key))
        {
            if (_valorActual.Length >= 25) return;
            _valorActual += key.ToString();
            _display.Text = _valorActual;
            return;
        }


        switch (key)
        {
            // Punto decimal (si ya hay uno no hace nada)
            case '.':
                if (!_valorActual.Contains("."))
                {
                    _valorActual += _valorActual.Length == 0 ? "0." : ".";
                    _display.Text = _valorActual;
                }
                break;
            // Operaciones binarias. Ejecuta la operación pendiente (si la hay)
            // y se establece como pendiente la pulsada
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                EjecutarOperacionPendiente();
                _operacionPendiente = key;
                break;
            // Otras operaciones
            // Cambio de signo
            case '±':
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                EjecutarOperacionInmediata('±');
                break;
            // raíz cuadrada
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
                EjecutarOperacionInmediata('r');
                break;
            // inverso (1/x)
            case 'i':
            case 'I':
                EjecutarOperacionInmediata('i');
                break;
            case '%':
                // Es un caso particular: de ejecución inmediata
                // pero utiliza dos variables para el cálculo
                EjecutarPorcentaje();
                break;
            // Igual/Enter (resultado)
            case '=':
            case '\r':
                EjecutarOperacionPendiente();
                break;
            // Retroceso (backspace)
            case '\b':
                if (_valorActual.Length > 0)
                {
                    _valorActual = _valorActual.Remove(_valorActual.Length - 1);
                    _display.Text = _valorActual;
                }
                break;
            // Suprimir/E. Eliminar valor actual
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                _valorActual = "";
                _display.Text = @"0";
                break;
            // Escape/C. Resetear (reiniciar)
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                _resultado = 0;
                _valorActual = "";
                _display.Text = @"0";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void EjecutarPorcentaje()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_display.Text) || _display.Text==@"0")
            return;

        var valor = double.Parse(_display.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        valor = _resultado * valor / 100;
        _valorActual = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        _display.Text = _valorActual;
    }

    private void EjecutarOperacionPendiente()
    {
        if (_valorActual.Length <= 0) return;

        var valor = double.Parse(_valorActual, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        switch (_operacionPendiente)
        {
            case '+':
                _resultado += valor;
                break;
            case '-':
                _resultado -= valor;
                break;
            case '*':
                _resultado *= valor;
                break;
            case '/':
                _resultado /= valor;
                break;
            default:
                _resultado = valor;
                break;
        }
        _valorActual = "";
        _operacionPendiente = char.MinValue;
        _display.Text = _resultado.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private void EjecutarOperacionInmediata(char operacion)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_valorActual) && _valorActual != @"0")
        {
            _valorActual = AplicarAValor(operacion, _valorActual);
            _display.Text = _valorActual;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_display.Text) && _display.Text != @"0")
            {
                _resultado = AplicarAValor(operacion, _resultado);
                _display.Text = _resultado.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }

    private string AplicarAValor(char operacion, string valor)
    {
        switch (operacion)
        {
            case '±':
                return valor.StartsWith("-") ? valor.Substring(1) : $"-{valor}";
            case 'r':
            case 'i':
                var numerico = double.Parse(valor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return AplicarAValor(operacion, numerico).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            default:
                return valor;
        }
    }

    private double AplicarAValor(char operacion, double valor)
    {
        switch (operacion)
        {
            case '±':
                return -valor;
            case 'r':
                return Math.Sqrt(valor);
            case 'i':
                return 1 / valor;
            default:
                return valor;
        }
    }

}
```

Los controles y sus propiedades se crean en el constructor. De esta forma puedes copiar el código en un formulario vacío para verlo funcionando.

Todos los eventos acaban llamando al evento `TeclaPulsada`, que es desde donde se lanza toda la lógica independientemente del evento generado por el usuario.

Como puedes ver para capturar el evento de la tecla Suprimir capturo el evento `KeyDown` del formulario.

Evidentemente falta funcionalidad por implementar como puede ser el control de errores (raíces cuadradas de valores negativos, divisiones entre 0, números excesivamente grandes, ....) pero creo que te puede servir de ayuda.